# Interpreting a negative confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

How do I interpret a negative confidence interval when comparing two population means?

For example, a confidence interval is $(-23.11, -1.02)$, what is the significance of these values being negative? Is it strictly signifying that $\bar{x}_1 < \bar{x}_2$ ?

Comment: Basically, statistically yes, but there are a couple more technical details (e.g. the type I error rate and the percentage of the confidence interval, etc.) Maybe this [page](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/logic_of_hypothesis_testing/sign_conf.html) can give you some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your hypothesis first :)

But I guess your hyp was x_1 >= x_2 ? Then we can say that we are (1-alfa)% confident that the difference between the true mean of x_1 and x_2 is between (−23.11,−1.02)